# How to use array directly in sql query for updating multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I know it is possible to update multiple rows by using following query

```
UPDATE MyProject\Model\User u SET u.password = 'new' WHERE u.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

My doubt is that if I have an array $array = [1,2,3] , I can use this array directly in the query, without iterating, is it possible?

Comment: satish sharma am trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE `MyProject` INNER JOIN `Model` INNER JOIN `Model` SET password='new' WHERE id IN(1,2,3)";
```

IF you have array of `ids` you can use it in `IN`

```
$array_of_id = array(1,3,5,8);
$in_text = implode(",", $array_of_id);
$sql = "UPDATE `MyProject` INNER JOIN `Model` INNER JOIN `Model` SET password='new' WHERE id IN($in_text)";
```